# What are the pros and cons of quitting before getting fired?

Tags: job-search, united-states, quitting, termination

What are the pros and cons of quitting before getting fired or laid off?

Presumably, if you quit, you lose your unemployment benefits. On the other hand, if following your job termination, you try to work for yourself (e.g. do a start-up) for a while, that fails, and you look for a job again in a year or so, your job history may include "quit his job to start a company that failed to take off" vs "was laid off / fired and then ..."

Comment: How can you be certain if you have not been told yet?

Comment: Which is it Fired or Being Made Redundant (laid off) - not e that A layoff is different to a redundancy situation

Comment: It looks as if we are missing information here. Why are you getting fired? Why would you throw away possible benefits that come with being fired when you don't have a new job yet?

Comment: I would never just quit. I would put in a two week notice.

Comment: "Presumably prospective employers can learn that by calling your old HR" I think that would violate privacy laws unless you gave your permission.

Comment: In the best situation, one would be savvy to impeding lay-offs, find another position, and quit before the layoff occurs. Getting fired is the worst, but being caught up in a layoff has a stigma as well, unfortunately.

Comment: @teego1967, during the dot com crisis when many companies went bankrupt the rule was to get yourself laid off when the company still had money to make redundancy payments, and quit if they didn't have money to pay salaries anymore. And no expenses on your own credit card!

Answer (score 4):

It matters a lot whether it is fired or laid off.  If you're going to be laid off, that doesn't look bad to future employers, you're eligible for unemployment, and you should never quit first.

If you're going to be fired, that's not so clear cut.  Both quitting and being fired look bad to potential employers.  And you generally look more attractive to future employers when you have a job, so cutting loose early only gives an advantage in giving you more time to look for the next job.  You are sometimes eligible for unemployment even when fired.

If you work for an employer that fires for flaky reasons, it might be better to keep working well, and wait for the firing.  A reputation like that gets around, and it's not as much of a disgrace to be fired from a place like that.

If you're truly a bad worker and deserve firing, then perhaps being a quitter won't look as bad.  If you can give a good justification for leaving the job without another, that could be your best bet.

(I once left a job without another because of family issues that needed my attention.  A reason like that used for leaving a job doesn't look as bad.  It's not great, but not terrible either.)

Comment: "You are sometimes eligible for unemployment even when fired." You are generally always eligible for unemployment when fired, unless it's for "misconduct". Misconduct has a high legal burden of proof and it's the company's burden to prove it.

Comment: "It matters a lot whether it is fired or laid off." The difference is kind of subjective. It is which one the employer says it is. Objectively, there is generally no distinction.

Comment: @user:Almost all background check forms will ask if you've been fired "for cause" from a previous position in the last x years. Truthfully answering NO to this question does make quite a difference. Generally, if a company is willing to go through the expense of performing a background check they will likely also be able to determine if you were fired or laid-off, even if they won't tell you that they've found out this information. If you put NO for being fired but their "sources" say yes then automatically kiss that job good-bye. If you say YES then probably kiss that job good-bye. It matters

Comment: @Dunk: and how do you define "for cause"? whatever the employer says it is?

Comment: @user102008 I've been laid off twice and was told it was a layoff and thus can say I was not fired.  It had nothing to do with my performance, and I've been able to get good references from those places.  Objectively, there is as great a distinction between laid off and fired as leaving for any other reason.  Yes, sometimes a layoff is a gentle or lazy firing, but usually, it's just a layoff: company needs to shed some costs quickly, employee has a weak manager or less important work or for some other reason gets in the cross hairs.  Good employees are laid off too.

Comment: @user:"For cause" means something "you did" specifically that caused the company to let you go. Almost always this is some sort of infraction. Being laid off because your company doesn't have enough work is not considered "for cause" because it wasn't something you did in particular. Poor job performance is kind of a gray area with regards to "for cause".  Also, I agree with Thursday, good employees do get laid off.(e.g. the employee just finished or is finishing a project and doesn't have a new one yet;Re-orgs; Management changes; Politics; Poor manager, etc...).

Comment: @Dunk: Right, and whether "something "you did" specifically that caused the company to let you go" is subjective; the company can claim it is or not. I do not believe it is a legally meaningful term.

Comment: @user102008 Usually a RIF involves more than one person, and there can be legal requirements for a company depending on its size and the number of employees being laid off.  A company can use the term 'laid off' in a subjective way, but there are clear, objective meanings in use as well.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it make sense to quit on your own?

Absolutely not.

If you get laid off you are eligible for a lot of different things, such as government programs (depending on your locality) or potentially even severance packages from your employer.

But what you should do is begin looking for jobs. Ideally you get laid off, collect a severance package, and then start your next job the day after you are unemployed.

Being laid off happens. As long as your reasons for getting laid off aren't, "terrible employee and got fired" and you don't have a streak of being laid off every 6 months for years it's not a bid deal.